# Cannot create payouts: this account has requirements that need to be collected.. Please provide those fields to re-enable payouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-payments-js

I am using **test api keys** in order to test payouts with stripe.
My stripe account shows me: **We couldn’t verify the tax ID provided for your business.** though I am in Test mode...

Here is my NodeJS backend:

```
const account = await stripe.accounts.create(
        {
          type: 'custom',
          email: 'asdasd@gmail.com',
          country: 'US',
          business_type: 'individual',

          individual: {
            id_number: '000000000',
            first_name: 'Firstname',
            last_name: 'Lastname',
            dob: {
              day: 1,
              month: 1,
              year: 1901,
            },
            email: 'asdasd@gmail.com',
            phone: '9723908360',

            address: {
              city: 'Allen',
              line1: 'address_full_match',
              line2: 'any',
              state: 'Texas',
              country: 'US',
              postal_code: '75462',
            },
          },
          capabilities: {
            card_payments: { requested: true },
            transfers: { requested: true },
          },
          external_account: {
            object: 'bank_account',
            country: 'US',
            currency: 'usd',
            routing_number: '110000000',
            account_number: '000123456789',
            account_holder_name: 'Firstname Lastname',
            account_holder_type: 'individual',
          },
        },
        {
          apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
        },
      )
```

On the next line I'm making the payout itself:

```
       await stripe.payouts.create(
          {
            source_type: 'card',
            method: 'standard',
            amount: 100,
            currency: 'USD',
          },
          {
            stripeAccount: account.id,
          },
        )
```

On trying to **stripe.payouts.create(...)** if throws me the following error:

```
{
  code: 'payouts_not_allowed',
  doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/payouts-not-allowed',
  message: 'Cannot create payouts: this account has requirements that need to be collected.. Please provide those fields to re-enable payouts.',
  type: 'invalid_request_error',
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Tue, 22 Feb 2022 15:35:16 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '315',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'idempotency-key': '__some_key___',
    'original-request': '__some_original_request__',
    'request-id': '__some_request_id__',
    'stripe-account': '__stripe_account__',
    'stripe-should-retry': 'false',
    'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  statusCode: 400,
  requestId: '__request_id___'
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, Have you got any updates? I have the same issue. Please let me know if you find any solution

Thanks

Comment: Hey, since I postponed this project, I didn't test the payment again to see if it's Restricted or not, but I believe this problem arises when you don't have your Stripe account activated

Comment: I'd suggest you to join Stripe Discord Channel and ask for some help there from the developers/support team. They indeed are very fast to response (seems they are 24/7 online) and vey are very organized and have access to each stripe client so they can find the problem for you